# iOS app In-App-Purchase for existing live paid app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a paid iPhone/iPad app that is live in the app store but my client what to implement the payment as an IAP process (In App Purchase). My question is, how do I handle customers that have already paid for the app.

Existing users should not be forced to pay for the app again with the new IAP, so somehow I must disable the IAP for customers that have already installed the app.

Is there a way I can check the first install date of the app, so I can use this to check if IAP should be enabled or disabled?

Or is there another way?

(not asking for code about how to implement IAP)

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is whenever releasing a paid app, I set the `NSUserDefaults` key like `@"hasPaidForThisApp"` `TRUE`. In case I change my mind in the future and want the app to be freemium I can always give users with this key set to true access to all parts of the app.

This method fails however, when deleting and reinstalling the app but it is the best I've come up with.

Comment: To overcome the problem with NSUserDefaults, you can use Keychain (google SFHFKeychainUtils) and it will work after reinstalling the app. My problem is, I haven't added a nice "haspaidforthisapp" :)